# Understanding Complex FFT Output of FFTW in Fortran

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, fft, fftw

I am currently using the **FFTW3** library to perform a 3d fast Fourier transform
with respect to a **3d set of complex data** (complex values of an orbital in space, at a set of grid points (x,y,z)).

Actually, each sampling direction holds M = 2*N+1 sampling points.To give an example, x,y and the z direction feature (21 points here) [-10,-9,...,0,1,...,9,10] and in this case the grid spacing is dr=1.

Consequently, I am considering an array of size data(M,M,M). The data is stored intuitively data(x,y,z), i.e. data(1,1,1) corresponds to the complex value at the grid point (-10,-10,-10), whereas data(21,21,21) features the value at the space point (10,10,10); (data(11,11,11) should correspond to grid point (x=0,y=0,z=0)).

Excerpt from my **Fortran** foo.f90 program (modified for simplicity).

```
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(4.0d0)
    integer, parameter :: dpc = kind(8.0d0)
    !library
    include "fftw3.f"
    integer(dpc) :: plan_forward

    !Number of Data points (same for each direction x,y,z)
    integer(dp),parameter :: M = 21

    ! Complex in- and output
    complex(dpc), dimension(M,M,M) :: data
    complex(dpc), dimension(M,M,M)  :: FT



    ! Make a plan for the FFT, and forward transform the data.

   call dfftw_plan_dft_3d ( plan_forward, M, M, M,data ,FT ,FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE )


   call dfftw_execute ( plan_forward, data, FT )
```

Further, my fourier transformed output FT is of the size MxMxM again.
(I have crosschecked: Performing an inverse Fourier transform (FFTW_BACKWARD), recovers my initial set of raw data(x,y,z).)

---

Now addressing my problem, since I got my self confused over reading about the 1d,2d and 3d cases (both real and complex):
I need to figure out, **which array entry corresponds to which reciprocal k vector/value**, or in other words: which **k**-vector (kx,ky,z) does correspond to FT(1,1,1), FT(11,11,11), FT(21,21,21) and so on.

Moreover, I am also not sure about: Which range are my kx,ky,kz values in and what's the reciprocal grid spacing (dk)?

My thoughts about this:

(i)
So first of all, the largest k-vector (kmax) - for each direction kx,ky,kz -should be defined by the smallest wavelength, which is determined by the size of my grid and its spacing dr.

kmax= 2*pi / dr (same for all directions kx,kx,kz)

(ii)
My spacing in k-space, on the other hand, is defined by the largest wavelength fitting in my box:

dk= 2*pi / ( (M-1)*dr )

(iii) Each k-direction consists of M points in this reciprocal space (for each direction kx,ky,kz). However, to figure out the range of kx,ky,kz I have to consider the Nquist-shannon theorem (am I right?): As a consequence, kx (and ky, kz respictively) is in the range of [-kmax/2, ...,0,..., kmax/2] with discrete steps of dk.

---

I'd be very thankful for any thoughts about, which array entry of the fourier transformed MxMxM  of FT corresponds to which reciprocal **k** value and how to figure out the right corresponding kx,ky,kz values and ranges.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention of all who follow Fortran. Fortran 90 is only one old, now quite obsolete, version, much fewer people follow this tag. Also note that the kind=4 and kind=8 is really ugly and not portable.

Comment: Also note that the legacy FFTW interface is also obsolete and there is a new one using Fortran 2003. You are using it in a not so safe way http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/FFTW-Execution-in-Fortran.html and the procedure names are strange. Where did you get the trailing underscore `_`?

Comment: See the manual for exact definitions http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029.html#The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029 (it mentions your problem iii using different words and more).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @Vladimir F. I am using an example.f90 which I found here: [link](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/fftw3/fftw3.html)

This is where the underscore _ is also from. I'll try to update to the newer fftw version (and update my example here). With regard to [link](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029.html#The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029) : Is it clear to you, that for the 3d complex case the array elements are arranged in the same manner?

Comment: Yes, the 3D case is the same (it is a separable product).

Comment: Thank you again! I have updated my example, I hope I've got it right: (1)
`call dfftw_execute ( plan_forward, data, FT )` should make it safe. (2) Introducing `integer, parameter :: dpc = kind(8.0d0)` makes it portable?

Comment: And last but not least, if I get right (and maybe it's helpful to some others):
Lets say I have `n=4` sampling points in the x direction `[1,2,3,4]` then this relates to the following kx values: `[0,1/4,2/4,-1/4]` , since `kx -1/4 = -k/n` is the same kx for `(4-1)/4 = (n-k)/4` for k=3.

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct. I personally use the modern interface in fftw3.f03, but it should work the same.

Comment: @JimmyPop I believe that is not entirely correct. Suppose a 1d-array contains `n` equally spaced samples of some physical quantity with "size" of `l_phys` [whatever units: time, length...]. Then the interval `dx` between two indices `i, i+1` in real space will be obviously `l_phys/n`, and the interval `dk` between two indices `i, i+1` in k-space should be `2*pi/l_phys`.